# PHP logging out by using class

Tags: php, oop

I need some help on my log out. I try to show less code as possible to avoid long code.

What I'm trying to do is a webpage that allow user to log in and view some stuff. When the user done viewing the stuff, the user are able to log out. When logging out, it'll redirect the user to login page and update my database to clear up all the data such as `session_id` etc.

But the problem is, whenever the user click the log out button, it'll redirect the user to the login page, but not updating the query which is in the `logout` function. I'm trying to logs the user out by clearing all the session and data in the database such as `session_id`, `last_log`, etc.

Is there any way to make the log out button works?

In my protect class

```
class protect
{
    var $username = "";
    var $password = "";
    var $id = "";
    var $isAdmin = -1;
    var $sess_id = "";
    var $action = "";
    var $query = "";
    var $ip_address = "";
    var $otp = "";

    function __construct()
    {
         try
         {
            session_start();
            $db = new DB("XXUser","password",DB_NAME);
            $db->connect();

            $this->check_login($db);
            if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin']!=1)
            {
                $this->logout($db);
            }

            else
            {
                if($this->action == "logout")
                {
                   $this->logout($db);
                }

                $this->check_session($db);
            }
         }

         catch
         {
              $this->logout($db);
              exit();
         }
    }

    function post_value()
    {
        if (!empty($_POST))
        {
            foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
            {
                $this->$key=$value;
            }
        } 
    }

    function get_value()
    {   
        if(isset($_GET['action']))
        {
            $this->action=$_GET['action'];
        }
    }

    function insert_session($db)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE myuser SET lastLog = now(), active = 'Y', last_active     
        = now(), last_access = now(), ip_addr = '".$this->ip_address."',  
        session_ID = '".trim($this->sess_id)."', fail_login_count = 0, 
        last_fail_login_time ='1900-01-01 00:00:00', otp = 
        '".$_SESSION['otp']."'  WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."'";

        $db->query($sql);
    }

    function check_session($db)
    {       
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin'] == 1)
        {
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM myuser WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."'     
            AND otp = '".$_SESSION['otp']."'";

            $db->query($sql2);
            $db->fetchRow();

            if($db->resultCount() == 0)
            {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Access Denied\");
                </script>";

                session_destroy();
                $db->disconnect();
                header("Location: login2.php");
                exit();

            }

            else
            {
                $this->check_time($db);
                $this->refresh_session();
            }
        }
    }

    function refresh_session()
    {
        //Regenerate id
        session_regenerate_id();

        //Regenerate otp
        $_SESSION['otp'] = trim(md5(time() .$_SESSION['id']));
    }

    function check_time($db)
    {
        $sql3 = "SELECT * FROM myuser WHERE ID = '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND 
        otp = '".$_SESSION['otp']."' AND last_active > DATE_SUB(NOW(), 
        INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)";

        $db->query($sql3);

        if($db->resultCount($db) == 0)
        {
            $this->logout($db);
        }

        else
        {
            $sql2 = "UPDATE myuser SET last_active = now() WHERE ID = 
            '".$_SESSION['id']."' AND otp = '".$_SESSION['otp']."'";

            $db->query($sql2);
        }
    }

    function check_login($db)
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin']!=1)
        {
            $this->username = sanitize($_POST['username']);
            $this->password = $_POST['password'];

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM myuser WHERE userName = '".$this-
            >username."' AND userPass = '".$this->password."'";

            $db->query($sql);

            if($db->resultCount() == 0)
            {
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Wrong Username or Password\");
                </script>";

                $db->disconnect();
                $db->clear();
            }

            else
            {
                $db->fetchRow();

                //Correct username but wrong password.
                if($db->record['userName'] == $this->username)
                {
                    if($db->record['userPass'] != $this->password)
                    {
                        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                            alert(\"Wrong Username or Password\");
                        </script>";
                        $sql3 = "UPDATE myuser SET ip_addr='".$this-
                        >ip_address."',fail_login_count=(fail_login_count+1) 
                        WHERE userName='".$this->username."'";

                        mysql_query($sql3) or die(mysql_error());
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        $this->id = $db->record['ID'];
                        $sql4 = "SELECT * FROM subordinate_reporting WHERE     
                        myuser_uid = '".$this->id."'";

                        $db->query($sql4);

                        if($db->record['active'] == 'Y')
                        {
                            session_destroy();
                            $db->disconnect();
                            header("Location: login2.php");
                            exit();
                        }

                        else if($db->resultCount() == 0)
                        {
                            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                                alert(\"".$db->record['real_name'].", You     
                                are not authorized to access this page\");
                            </script>";
                            $db->clear();
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                                alert(\"Welcome ".$db-
                                >record['real_name'].". Your last access was     
                                on ".$db->record['last_access']."\");
                            </script>";

                            $this->session($db);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //This function haven't use
    function check_attempt($db)
    {
        $db->query("SELECT fail_login_count, last_fail_login_time FROM 
        myuser WHERE userName = ".$this->username."");
        $db->fetchRow();

        if($db->record['fail_login_count'] >= 3)
        {
            $db->query("UPDATE myuser SET blocked = 'Y', 
            last_fail_login_time = now()");

            echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                alert(\"Your account has been blocked for 10 minutes due to     
                failed login attempts of 3 times\");
            </script>";
        }

        if($db->record['blocked'] === 'Y')
        {
            if(($db->record['last_fail_login_time'] - time()) > 10)
            {
                $db->clear();
                $db->query("UPDATE myuser SET last_fail_login_time = '1900-    
                01-01 00:00:00', fail_login_count = 0, blocked = 'N'");
            }

            else
            {
                $db->clear();
                echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
                    alert(\"Please try again later\");
                </script>";
            }
        }
    }

    function logout($db)
    {
            $sql = "UPDATE myuser SET session_ID = '', otp = '', active = 
            'N', last_active = '1900-01-01 00:00:00', lastLog = '1900-01-01         
            00:00:00' WHERE ID = ".$_SESSION['id']." AND 
            otp='".$_SESSION['otp']."'";

            $db->query($sql);
            echo $sql;
            unset ($_SESSION['otp']);
            unset ($_SESSION['loggedin']);
            unset ($_SESSION['id']);
            session_unset();
            session_destroy();
            $db->clear();
            $db->disconnect();
            header("Location: login2.php");
            exit();
    }

    function session($db)
    {
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 1;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $this->id;
        $_SESSION['otp'] = trim(md5(time() .$_SESSION['id']));
        $this->ip_address = $this->get_ip();
        $this->sess_id = session_id();
        $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
        $this->insert_session($db);
    }

    function logout_btn()
    {
            echo "<form name='logoutbtn' method='post' action=''>";
            echo "\n&nbsp;<input type='hidden' name='action' value='logout'                 
            />";
            echo "<input type='submit' id='button' value='Log Out' />";
            echo "\n</form>";
    }

    function get_ip()
    {
        if(getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP'))
        {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_CLIENT_IP');
        }

        else if(getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'))
        {
            $ip = getenv('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR');
        }
        else
        {                                     
            $ip = getenv('REMOTE_ADDR');
        }

        return $ip;                                         
    }
}
```

In my normal html file

```
<?php
try
{
    $prot = new protect();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) || $_SESSION['loggedin']!=1)
    {
        echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">
            alert("Access Denied");
        </script>";
    }
}

catch (Exception $e)
{
    $e->getMessage();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
</html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
$ved = new view_exit_docket($db, $_SESSION['id']);
$ved->check_app_uid($db);
$ved->display_table($db);
$prot->logout_btn();
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try outputting any MySQL error, maybe it's just an SQL syntax error. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Zeke I tried using mysql_error and it didn't show any error. I don't think it's a syntax error as this code used to work before when I put all the code together in a single file. Since I separate to 2 files and use class, some problem occur but I fixed it, but not this log out problem.

Comment: Ok, then check your DB class, whatever that is. You'd be better off using mysqli. In any case you should be checking for success on every critical point of your code to trace and debug.

Comment: @Zeke thank you for your time, I already update my code, can you help me check if there is any error? I will check my DB class. for any error.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've been busy. Well, if you still have problems, I guess I can help you if you show me all the files affecting this particular issue. You may send an email to stackoverflow@snowlinks.net and I'll read it. I can definitely simulate it all on my local server.

Comment: @Zeke It's ok, I've already solve the problem by creating a log out form in the view_exit_docket class and passing the logout function from protect class into the class(view_exit_docket). Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

If the log out button was not working, then surely you would not have been redirected - this implies that failures are occurring elsewhere.

I will assume that some of the stuff you have edited out of your code is critical to its operation (other wise it would **not** behave as you describe).

> it'll redirect the user to the login page, but not updating the query

From the code you've shown us, the only route to the redirection is through executing the query. If the data was not changed, then the query failed.

1) You didn't tell us anything about the DB class.

2) You don't check the return value from $DB->query() nor poll the state of the operation from $DB after executing the query. If you had, you might have got an error message explaining the problem.

3) You didn't show us the SQL you are running (the most likely place where the fault lies).

4) You have not said what happened to the session data

Comment: I'll edit to show you my full code. I hope that my code won't be the worse code you have ever seen as my aim is to only make the code work.

Comment: I already update my code. Please help me check if there is any error.